# Association Rules Error

Tags: r, arules

I am running the formula that is given below in R

```
rules <- apriori(B4_Temp,
  parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.001, conf=0.6,target="rules"),
  appearance = list(rhs=c("Location Info=Level1"),default="lhs"),
  control = list(verbose=F))
```

I am getting this error as:

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Location Info=Level1 is an unknown item label,
  Location Info=Entrance is an unknown item label
```

But I have those values in the data set. What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide an example of your dataset

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem. Take a look at `B4_Temp` and be sure that your dataset is represented like you are naming there on `rhs=c("Location Info=Level1")`. Maybe this data's representation is not consistent with your dataset in `B4_Temp`.

Just remember: the meaning of "item label" is all about the "stuff" you have stored in your data set. If this "stuff" is not equal to the parameter you are trying to set on rhs an error will happen.

It happened with me because my equivalent `B4_Temp` was with an error in the way I put the "stuff" inside it. My separator was a semi-colon but inside of my equivalent `B4_temp` there were some characters that was not consistent with the context; for example, there was also the character ".

When I remade my equivalent `B4_Temp` correctly, I fixed it.